# Turn on and off pconnect

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I can turn php pconnect on and off with a config variable. but how can I tell if it actually is on or off? Is there a command on the server to check this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try using [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-stat.php) function

Answer (score 1):

```
$pconnect_allowed = ini_get("mysql.allow_persistent");
```

[mysql.allow_persistent docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.allow-persistent) and [ini_get docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php)

> A boolean ini value of off will be returned as an empty string or "0" while a boolean ini value of on will be returned as "1". The function can also return the literal string of INI value.